# How to get entity of a channel using Telethon bot API?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

I cannot get_dialogs with Telethon Bot since the method is only available for a client. Therefore when I try to access the entity with its id I receive an error. How do I access an entity(channel) if I cannot parse all channels and neither access them by id? I would like to parse messages from a private group and use Telegram Bot for it.

Comment: would be helpful if you tell us what the error is

Comment: Hi @painor! Thank you for your response. The error is the following:
`telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PeerIdInvalidError: An invalid Peer was used. Make sure to pass the right peer type (caused by ForwardMessagesRequest)`
It's there because Telethon does not know which channel this ID relates to. According to docs I need to list all of the dialogs first and then get entity by id. Please, check this link [link](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/entities.html#summary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the bot to the channel while it's running should be enough for the bot to obtain its access hash. Alternatively, sending a message there while the bot is inside should also work. This hash will be saved to the `.session` file. Regardless, if you use the "marked" ID (for channels, prefix -100 to the real ID or use `types.PeerChannel(real id)`), Telethon will know you mean a channel, which can help make it work.

Comment: Hi @Lonami! Thank you for your answer! Is it possible for a bot to scrap other channels than the one it's connected to? I am developing a bot for myself that parses posts from several channels, filters them, and sends them to me.

Comment: Ohh, I think I got it. The bot is not a member of those channels and therefore cannot scrap messages.